# SQL group by where values are same within group

Tags: mysql

So, I have a table with which individuals (person_id) have multiple lines (up to 4) and values for a column (value_column) can either = 0 or 1

I'd like to write a piece of code that returns a row for each person_id in which their value for value_column is only 0 or only 1 (even though they may have 3 or 4 rows each)

It's probably an easy line of code, but for someone with less SQL experience, it seems nearly impossible!

EDIT: here is a quick sample of lines:

```
person_id  value_column
A          0
A          1
A          0
B          0
B          0
B          0
B          0
C          1
C          1
C          1
```

And I would expect the line of code to return the folowing:

```
person_id value_column
B          0
C          1
```

Comment: Please post a sample of rows along with a sample of what you would expect the query output to be.

Comment: So your intent is to exclude `person_id = 'A'` because 'A' has _both_ a 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, and to only return one row for person_id = 'B' and person_id = 'C'

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this probably

```
select distinct * from table1
where person_id in
( select person_id
  from table1
  group by person_id
  having count(distinct value_column) <= 1
)
```

Inner query, will return only those `person_id` for which there is only one `value_column` present and that's the same thing getting done by `count(distinct value_column) <= 1` and then outer query just selects everything for those person_id.

Comment: Please add an explanation for the OP and future readers on how the `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT)` is working here...

Comment: Yes definitely and it was interrupted by power cut. Anyways added now. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Very close, but rather than than returning multiple repeating values of person_id, how could I return only one row per person_id? That is, now the we know that the person_ids returned all have only one distinct value of column_value, then, how can we return just one unique instance of each?

Comment: Just use a `distinct` keyword in outer select.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from myTable where person_id not in 
(select a.person_id from myTable a, myTable b
  where a.person_id = b.person_id
    and a.value_column <> b.value_column)
```

Get persons with different values and then get those who are not in this first query.

Or quicker and nicer :

```
select person_id, min(value_column)
 from myTable
 group by person_id
 having min(value_column)=max(value_column)
```